# Call private member within the method belonging to the class itself

Tags: c++

I encountered this problem when implementing a class:

```
class Cell {
     bool isAlive;
     int numNeighbours;
     //...omit irrelavent private members



     public:
         Cell();  // Default constructor
         ~Cell(); // Destructor


      void setLiving();   

     ....         
    };
    void Cell::setLiving(){
         isAlive=true;
       }


 class Grid{...
  friend std::ostream& ::operator(std::ostream& out, const Grid &g);
  };//...omit

 std::ostream& ::operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Grid &g){
 int i,j;
 for(i=0;i<g.gridSize;i++){
   for(j=0;j<g.gridSize;j++){
         if(**g.theGrid[i][j].isAliv*e*) out<<"X";
         else out<<"_";
    }
    out<<endl;
   }
    return out;
  }
```

The complier said that "isAlive" is a private member so I can't call it that way
I think the problem is at "g.theGrid[i][j].isAlive"
I tried to friend class Grid but it didnt help

Comment: The *actual* code would probably help.

Comment: I hope it it doesn't have anything to do with the missing semicolon after the class definition.

Comment: Something is wrong in part of the code you didn't show us.

Comment: Not the case of semicolon.in terms of actual code,the complier gimme that when overloading <<,the code is below:

Comment: The compiler will typically tell you exactly which line the error is on.  You shouldn't need to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned `operator<<` — it's most likely a free function, so it needs to be declared as `friend` to be able to access private members.

```
class Cell {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Grid&);
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I have this part in my class Cell.Sorry for not including in the OP

Comment: @y26jin: No, you've got friend declaration for `Grid`, but you want to access `Cell`. I've edited my snippet to reflect that it's `operator<<` for `Grid`.

Comment: It worked ! so in order to access class Cell in my overloading func I have to friend my overloading func right

Answer (score 0):

The class member isAlive is private, so the operator didn't have the right to access it, you need to put a friend declaration in the body of Cell's definition.

```
class Cell {
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Cell&);
// ...
```

};

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
if(**g.theGrid[i][j].isAlive) out<<"X"
```

Is accessing the private member 'isAlive'. I assume theGrid is a two dimensional array of Cell objects. You need a getLiving() method defined. Then use it here.

Answer (score -1):

isAlive is private, declare it as public...

EDIT1:

```
class Cell {
public:
   bool isAlive;
```

Update:

- private members of a class are accessible only from within other members of the same class or from their friends.
- protected members are accessible from members of their same class and from their friends, but also from members of their derived classes.
- Finally, public members are accessible from anywhere where the object is visible.

Comment: oh definitely I am just curious if it is possible to keep it private and figure out ways to call it

Comment: Changing the accessibility of fields just to shut the compiler up is typically not the best idea.  There are times when having public fields can make sense; this doesn't appear to be one of them.